# How to add user information to Airbrake notifications?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, airbrake

I have a Rails app which is sending Airbrake notifications fine, but I want to add some user information to the notifications.

I'm using the [airbrake gem](https://github.com/airbrake/airbrake), v5.7.1, which adds a [middleware](https://github.com/airbrake/airbrake/blob/master/lib/airbrake/rack/middleware.rb#L48) to capture uncaught exceptions and report them before re-raising.

I tried, as per the [README](https://github.com/airbrake/airbrake-ruby#airbrakeadd_filter), to add a filter, to an initializer:

```
class UserDetailsFilter
  def call(notice)
    if notice.stash.has_key?(:rack_request)
      user_credentials = notice.stash[:rack_request].cookies["user_credentials"]          
      unless user_credentials.blank?
        user_id = user_credentials.split(':').last
        user = User.find(user_id)
        notice[:params][:user_email] = user.email
        notice[:params][:user_name] = "#{user.first_name} #{user.last_name}"
      end
    end 
  end
end

Airbrake.add_filter(UserDetailsFilter.new)
```

Using `binding.pry` I can confirm that this code is run and that notice does have the `:params` hash modified. However the params in the Airbrake UI only have action and controller information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was a bug in the Airbrake gem which has been fixed and was released in [Airbrake 5.8.0](https://github.com/airbrake/airbrake/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#v580rc3-march-1-2017).

Answer (score 0):

I am not exactly sure why this information is not being displayed in the dashboard, it should be displayed in params just fine.

The Airbrake gem sets user information to `notice[:context][:user]` as per https://airbrake.io/docs/api/#create-notice-v3. You could try setting that information there.

Alternatively, if you can define a `current_user` method which carries the user object, then the library can guess the values you try to retrieve for you.

```
def current_user
  @current_user ||= User.find(user_id)
end
```

Comment: I have a `current_user` method in my controller already. Are you suggesting that I should get user information in the notifications without even having to add a filter?

Comment: Yes, I would expect that to happen. Could you send Airbrake support a message? I would like to check out your project.

Comment: I do, sorry, I should've clarified.

Comment: Automatic inclusion of user details via `ApplicationController#current_user` was not working because of a 'bug' in the airbrake gem, which has now been fixed on master branch: https://github.com/airbrake/airbrake/pull/684